# Java - Escaping characters directly in code vs in a properties file

Tags: java, compiler-construction

Does the java compiler automatically add an escape character if a string is not escaped and the value is stored in a properties file?

For example, the following statement generates a compiler error because of the \W character:

```
testRegex ="[ \t]*(Not\Wknown)[ \\t]*";
```

If however i store that string in a properties file and load it as it is, the compiler does not complain.

app.properties

```
regex.expr = [ \t]*(Not\Wknown)[ \\t]*
```

MyClass.java

```
testRegex = System.getProperty("regex.expr");
```

Does the compiler automatically escape the \W value?

Comment: The compiler doesn't even SEE properties files.  They're read at run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a properties file is read, the following rules apply.  This is from the [Javadoc for the Properties class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

> Characters in keys and elements can be represented in escape sequences similar to those used for character and string literals (see sections 3.3 and 3.10.6 of The Java™ Language Specification). The differences from the character escape sequences and Unicode escapes used for characters and strings are:
>
> - Octal escapes are not recognized.
> - The character sequence \b does not represent a backspace character.
> - The method does not treat a backslash character, \, before a non-valid escape character as an error; the backslash is silently dropped. For example, in a Java string the sequence "\z" would cause a compile time error. In contrast, this method silently drops the backslash. Therefore, this method treats the two character sequence "\b" as equivalent to the single character 'b'.
> - Escapes are not necessary for single and double quotes; however, by the rule above, single and double quote characters preceded by a backslash still yield single and double quote characters, respectively.
> - Only a single 'u' character is allowed in a Uniocde escape sequence.

So in the example that you site, `\W` would be treated as if it were only `W`.  But this is nothing to do with the compiler.  These rules are applied at run time.

Answer (score 2):

Escape characters are only necessary in `String` literals and `char` literal values because those are parsed by the compiler. If the `String` is read and created from some other source, it is not necessary.

From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6)

> The character and string escape sequences allow for the representation
>   of some nongraphic characters as well as the single quote, double
>   quote, and backslash characters in character literals (§3.10.4) and
>   string literals (§3.10.5).